# Unable to parseMongoDB to Python dataframe in multiple rows from one record document of Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

I have a very deep nested array structure in Mongo.
I am trying to unwind some of the data by aggregate function, however not sure what to do next to get the results in a particular format

Here is my sample json:

```
   {
      "_id": {
         "$oid": "asdf016303a7f6a"
      },
      "layout": [
         {            
            "id": "",
            "contents": [
               {
                  "columns": [
                     {
                        "items": [
                           {                            
                              "Answer": [],
                              "stopBlurSave": false
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "displayName": "Container"
               },
               {
                  "columns": [
                     {
                        "items": [
                           {
                              "isdirty": false,
                              "todaysDate": "03/21/2017"
                           },
                           {
                              "dbSettings": {
                                 "Name": "Name1",
                                 "Query": "Query1"
                                },
                              "new": false,
                              "stopBlurSave": false
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "items": [
                           {
                              "showEditPanel": false,
                              "isdirty": false
                           },
                           {
                              "islive": false,
                              "new": false
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "new": true
               },
               {
                  "showEditPanel": false,
                  "displayName": "Container",
                  "columns": [
                     {
                        "items": [
                           {
                              "dbSettings": {
                                 "Name": "Name2",
                                 "Query": "Query2"
                                },
                              "new": false,
                              "stopBlurSave": false
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ],
                  "new": true
               }
            ],
            "displayName": "Section"
         }
      ],
      "name": "Task Form"
   }
```

If you see inside layout.contents.columns.items array there may or may not be dbSettings.
I want to take the value in the dbSettings and then create a dataframe table like below

```
Name          DBName    Query
Task Form     Name1     Query1
Task Form     Name2     Query2
```

Currently i am trying with pymongo and doing the below aggregation

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'layout.contents.columns.items.dbSettings.Name': {
        '$exists': True
    }
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$layout.contents.columns.items.dbSettings', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$layout.contents.columns.items.dbSettings', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    },

    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'name': '$name',
            'db': '$layout.contents.columns.items.dbSettings.Name', 
            'query': '$layout.contents.columns.items.dbSettings.Query'
                }
    }
```

There are two issue here, after unwind all the data is in one column but all the null brackets are still there something like [][][][],,Name1,[]Name2[], i have tried unwind options but either those come or nothing comes in the output.
Second even after i replace everything in the data frame i am still unsure how to map it to a new row as each record can have many dbSettings i want to replicate it that many times (there is a 1:1 mapping with Name and Query).
Is it something Mongo aggregation can do or we have to do some other logic in python. Any directions are welcome.

Comment: Your top level object is an array which isn't a valid document structure in MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah, that array was coming when i exported as json from compass. In mongo it is not there. I have corrected it, thanks for pointing out.